# how a "property" can be call like it's a method without using parenthesis

Tags: javascript, chai

With the lib 'chai', I can do this:

```
expect(display).to.be.true;
```

if display is false, the test fail, if display is true, it work.

My issue is, how the lib chai can know that the ".true" property have-been used? There is no parenthesis and it's not even a method! What is the name of this syntaxe? How can I declare similar thing?

this lib have also a .false, and a .empty property, who can be used why the same syntaxe:

```
expect([]).to.be.empty;//OK
expect([1]).to.be.empty;//test fail
expect(false).to.be.false;//OK
expect(true).to.be.false;//test fail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects can have ["getter" and "setter" properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters). These invoke the function you provide upon access or update, respectively.

```js
var o = {
  get test() { console.log("foo!") }
}

o.test;
```

This is an ECMAScript 5 feature, and is widely available in modern  implementations.